# Associate CartoDB with local data

Tags: laravel, cartodb

I'm quite new to software such as CartoDB, I've already successfully create a map and add it a data set. My goal is to create a map with all administrative areas from each country (using http://www.gadm.org/version2). Each of those areas is reservable for user but here's my issue : where can I store which users own which areas ? I want to integrate this map with a Laravel back-end.

Answer (score 0):

You can access CartoDB data from your backend using [SQL API](https://docs.cartodb.com/cartodb-platform/sql-api/) to perform `SELECT`, `UPDATE` and `INSERT`'s. To render data on CartoDB you need it stored on a CartoDB Table so you will need to implement some kind of synchronization between your data repositories.